# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < while calling cakephp select form directly in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i have a basic problem related to javascript and PHP,

I am trying to include a select option in javascript. For debug purpose I did the same with input text box and it works fine. As soon as i load the options using cakephp form helper through a list of array passed from controller i get this above error. I will explain what i am trying to achieve with code example:

i have a form and a div tag where i want to append a select options using javascript, jquery in my case.

my view file:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('GenericDrug'); ?>
 <div class="voca">
 </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add" >
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add more
</button>


<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Values passed from my controller:

```
public function admin_edit($id = null) {
//other codes

$this->set(compact('drugClasses','genericDrugs','drugClassList'));
}
```

these classes are modeled using ORM

Now i want a jquery/javascript function such that it will append my select option in div tag classed as 'voca'.

So far i have done:
In my view file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = <?php echo $this->Form->input('drug_class_id'); ?>
$(function()
{
$(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
{

    $(i).appendTo( ".voca" );
</script>
```

input drugclassid will generate list of options for select. However, I tried a lot of fiddling around but cant find a solution. The page does get rendered at the backend and sends all the option data, however i get a javascript error message

[Click to see error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zem2F.png)

Comment: Keyword `quotes`

Comment: i did try everything. I tried using quotes differently .. the above example is just an example. i did try  var i = "<?php echo $this->Form->input('drug_class_id'); ?>";   also   var i = '<?php echo $this->Form->input('drug_class_id'); ?>'; and so on

Comment: You need to put the HTML in a string - wrap it in quotes. You'll also need to make sure the quotes within the string don't interfere with those you use to delimit the string, so you'll probably need to escape them at some point

Comment: do you mean var i = "<p><?php echo $this->Form->input('drug_class_id'); ?></p>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
    <script>
      var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($this->Form->input('drug_class_id')); ?>
    </script>
```